# Sencha Architecture Theming and CSS is not Working

Tags: sass, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

When i upgrade the version the css and theme is taking the default one .Architect shows error as
**Theme Error saving theme.Cmdenabled projects need to have a local library base path.Yours is set to "http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.1/"**

Answer (score 0):

likely you will want to set your library base path to to touch/, do this by selecting the Library node under resources.